# ZF2: Is there a more efficient way to do this Zend\Db Update query?

Tags: sql, zend-framework2

Here's some ZF1 code for an update query:

```
$this->getAdapter()->update(
    'users', $data, $this->getAdapter()->quoteInto('node_id = ?', $user->nodeId)
);
```

Here's the same query with ZF2:

```
    $param = $this->getAdapter()->platform->quoteValue($user->nodeId);
    $sqlOj = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
    $update = $sqlOj->update('users')->set($data)->where('node_id = ' . $param);
    $updateString = $sqlOj->getSqlStringForSqlObject($update);
    $this->getAdapter()->query($updateString, Adapter::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

As you can see, one line of ZF1 code has become 5 lines of ZF2 code, (actually without the fluent interface it would be 7 lines...)

Am I missing something?  Or is ZF2's DB component just more verbose that ZF1?

BTW, I have found the same scenario with select and insert queries too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to limit it to 3 lines.

```
use \Zend\Db\Sql\Sql;

$sql = new Sql ($adapter);
$update = $sql->update ('users')->set ($data)->where (['id = ?' => 1]);
$adapter->query ($sql->getSqlStringForSqlObject ($update), $db::QUERY_MODE_EXECUTE);
```

The problem is they didn't expect you to run your updates like that. Instead, you are expected to use a table gateway.
This way it becomes one line again:

```
$this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
```